# Chrome browser not launching with selenium 3.141.59 and chrome browser version 113.0.5672.127

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running simple java selenium script to open google.com in chrome browser.
Version of selenium is 3.141.59 and chrome browser version is 113.0.5672.127

**Here is the code:**

```
package demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestChrome { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\browser 
    driver\chromedriver.exe"); 
    ChromeDriver driver =new ChromeDriver(); 
    String url ="http://www.google.com"; 
    driver.get(url); 
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); 
  } 
}
```

**Error:**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 113.0.5672.63 (0e1a4471d5ae5bf128b1bd8f4d627c8cbd55f70c-refs/branch-heads/5672@{#912}) on port 2106
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'MAVCHN1121310', ip: '192.168.0.202', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E48893+48451]
    (No symbol) [0x00DDB8A1]
    (No symbol) [0x00CE5058]
    (No symbol) [0x00D05304]
    (No symbol) [0x00D01951]
    (No symbol) [0x00D00019]
    (No symbol) [0x00D30798]
    (No symbol) [0x00D3047C]
    (No symbol) [0x00D2A0B6]
    (No symbol) [0x00D07E08]
    (No symbol) [0x00D08F2D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010A8E3A+2540266]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010E8959+2801161]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010E295C+2776588]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00ED2280+612144]
    (No symbol) [0x00DE4F6C]
    (No symbol) [0x00DE11D8]
    (No symbol) [0x00DE12BB]
    (No symbol) [0x00DD4857]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75FA00C9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77307B4E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77307B1E+238]

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1002)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at demo.TestChrome.main(TestChrome.java:26)
```

Tried to use ChromeOptions with different arguments to overcome the error:

```
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();  options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*"); options.addArguments("--headless");  options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");  ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Nothing helped out.

Can you please provide solutions.

Comment: This is working after adding additional configuration , chrome.additional.capabilities={"chromeOptions":{"ags":["--remote-debugging-port=9222"]}} .But with this config I m not able to run parallel and sequential, can someone help me